# Get substring from string db2

Tags: sql, string, replace, db2

I have 2 strings for exampe:

```
FO-123-4444-3353-9999-TEXT and
123-4444-3353-88888-something
```

How can i get substring without TEXT,something on the end and if there is FO also without FO. FO will be always there or won't , but TEXT can have any other word instead

Final result shoul be:

```
123-4444-3353-88888 and
123-4444-3353-9999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace FO- in the beginning and -TEXT in the end, use regexp_replace. It can be done in single regexp using OR (|)

```
select regexp_replace('FO-123-4444-3353-9999-TEXT','^FO-|-TEXT$','') from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Result:

```
123-4444-3353-9999
```

Comment: What it TEXT change so i have at the end bla or any other word? Is maybe bettrr to use substring and to check occurence of the '-' ?

Comment: Ok i agree, your answer was the right one for my first question

Comment: @John for example select regexp_replace('FO-123-4444-3353-9999-TEXT','^FO-|-[^-]*$','') from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1  - this will remove any other characters which are not dash at he end, including last dash

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

Assuming that "TEXT" and "FO" do not appear anywhere else in the string (as in your examples), you can use `REPLACE()`:

```
select replace(replace(col, '-TEXT', ''), 'FO-', '')
```

For the revised question, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '^FO-|-TEXT[0-9]*$', '')
```

This assumes that the "FO" and "TEXT" are at the beginning and end of your strings.

Comment: FO appear or don't appear only once i the string, but TEXT value can be different, once TEXT,TEXT1...

Comment: What it TEXT change so i have at the end 'bla' or any other word?